# D3 How to style keys using their nested values

Tags: d3.js

I've nested my data to have keys of `'starting point'` and I'd like to use the values of each key for styling.

I've created a circle for each key and would like to use the value `'color'` to fill it. How can I access this? I've tried lots of things including

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.values.color
})
```

and

```
.data(function(d) {return d.values})
```

but I can never seem to do this unless I'm binding the values data. What should I do?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yjF4qOnL3Jxn1M5elzMx?p=info)

```
var newdata = [{
  'starting point': 'Berkner',
  'color': '#0084B5',
  'path': 'M 210.256,185.116'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Hercules',
  'color': '#E48428',
  'path': 'M 156.355,241.624'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Ronne',
  'color': '#009079',
  'path': 'M 195.123,218.287'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Ronne-Filchner',
  'color': '#D81D1F',
  'path': 'M 195.123,218.287'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Hut',
  'color': '#DB2882',
  'path': 'M 332.640,380.314'
}];


var startingpoint = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
  return d['starting point'];
  })
  .entries(newdata);

console.log(startingpoint)

var canvas = d3.select('#routes')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 700 500")
  .attr('width', "100%")
  .attr('height', "100%")
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)

var posEnter = canvas
  .selectAll(".route")
  .data(startingpoint)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr('class', 'route')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,30)')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key
  })

posEnter
  .append("circle")
  .attr('class', 'routemark')
  .attr('r', '10')

posEnter.select('.routemark')
  .attr('cx', '10')
  .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
    return i * 30
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.values.color
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects created by applying `d3.nest()` will have a property `values` which is an array:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Berkner",
    "values": [
      {
        "starting point": "Berkner",
        "color": "#0084B5",
        "path": "M 210.256,185.116"
      }
    ]
  },
```

See this snippet for an example:

```js
var newdata = [{
  'starting point': 'Berkner',
  'color': '#0084B5',
  'path': 'M 210.256,185.116'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Hercules',
  'color': '#E48428',
  'path': 'M 156.355,241.624'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Ronne',
  'color': '#009079',
  'path': 'M 195.123,218.287'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Ronne-Filchner',
  'color': '#D81D1F',
  'path': 'M 195.123,218.287'
}, {
  'starting point': 'Hut',
  'color': '#DB2882',
  'path': 'M 332.640,380.314'
}];


var startingpoint = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
  return d['starting point'];
  })
  .entries(newdata);
  
// Just output below
d3.select("#print")
  .text("startingpoint = \n" + JSON.stringify(startingpoint, null, "  "));
console.log(startingpoint)
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="print"></div>
```

For your code the solution should be as simple as this:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
  return d.values[0].color;   // access the array to get the first element's color
})
```

Comment: Thanks, thats really easy!

Comment: Can I use something similar to this if I have two keys? For example I want to find 'color', which is a value of 'path' which is a value of 'starting point'

Comment: `d.values[0].values[0].color`?

Comment: This, however, makes me wonder, why you are nesting your data in the first place, if there is just one object per level. Do you have full data, which deviates from the data you provided?

Comment: Thanks again and thanks for noticing - Yes there is a lot more data and its  useful for me to have several levels of groupings, so I think nest will work for me. I'm just finding it very tricky to find examples beyond how to create it

Comment: Have you seen [Mister Nester](http://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/raw/4748131/). This is really helpful when you are just starting to learn nesting.